# Different type of function composition

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

When I first heard about function composition in school, I also expected the graphs of the composed function to 'behave' like both simple functions that are composed.

Suppose we have f(x) = $x^2$ and $g(x) = \cos(x)$

The graph of $y = f(g(x))$ looks like in the first image:

[image: Graph of cosine squared function.]

But my instinct in school was to think that the graph looks like the second image:

Red curve represents f(x) = $x^2$ and the blue curve represents the result of the special composition $y = f(g(x))$.
[image: Graph of cosine on parabola.]

Think of this special type of composition as molding/transposing the X-axis on the graph/curve of the outer function in the composition and then draw the graph of the inner function on previously modified coordinates plane.

In the example above think of the parabola $x^2$ as the X-axis and then draw $ \cos(x)$ around this new X-axis (which is no longer a straight line).

My questions are:

1. Does this type of function composition have a name?
2. Has it been studied?
3. Are there any papers I can read on it?
4. If yes, how can I search about them?
5. I know that in this type of composition, the result might not be a function that can be written in explicit form $y=f(x)$, but when can it be?

As a final note, here is $\cos(x)$ composed with
$\frac{1}{6}\cos(6x)$. It looks nice, like the beginning of a fractal series.

Red curve represents $g(x) = \cos(x)$ and the blue curve represents the result of the special composition.

[image: Cosine on cosine graph.]

Comment: Where did that second image even come from? I can't reproduce what your thought was.

Comment: Your illustration of $f\circ g$ isn't even a function.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Back then I thought that function composition would take the graph of the inner function and distort/transmute it around the graph of the outer function. Something like treating the graph of the outer function as the OX axis (which is exactly what I did to get those images).

Comment: @lulu I briefly mentioned that on question number 5.

Comment: No...you mentioned that the composition wasn't a "*simple* function", but of course it is.

Comment: You are right. The result is not a function, What I wanted to ask was: when is the result a function and when is it not?

Comment: It is always a function, well trusting that $f$ and $g$ are, as in this case.

Comment: @lulu you said it yourself, that the second image is not a function, yet the second and third images are both from aku's composition and not the regular one.

Comment: I think my graphs are not clear enough. In both 2nd and 3rd images the red curve is the outer function in the composition and the blue curve is the result of said composition. The inner function from the composition is missing from the images

Comment: Not following.  $f\circ g  (x)=\cos^2 x$.  Using the double angle formula, that's the same as $\frac {\cos {2x}+1}2$.  Not sure what more there is to say.

Comment: It's obvious, for instance, that $0≤f\circ g(x)≤1$ for all $x$, unlike what you drew.

Comment: If you are trying to define some new multi-valued sort of composition, your definition is not clear.

Comment: Yes, 0≤f∘g(x)≤1 can be seen in the first image and that is the regular (only type?) of composition. Indeed I want to create or try to find out if somebody else already created this new type of composition.

Comment: If I have to name this operation, I would call it bending of a curve along another one. It seems more like an operation between two oriented planar curves with base point.

Comment: How would you bend $y=e^x$ around $y=x^2$? (or, $y=x^2$ around $y=e^x$?)

Answer (score 4):

First the bad news: I've spent significant time in or around a few different university math departments and I've never heard of anyone studying an operation like this. You can view that as a positive thing: you've probably invented an original concept! Now you just have to go write papers proving cool features of these compositions until other people get interested and it becomes a new field of math :)

The thinking does remind me of some differential geometry ideas like tangent spaces. You're basically trying to use the tangent space of the "main curve" as a coordinate system for the "offset curve".

### Formula for the new composition

Now the good news: I can give a (somewhat messy) formula that implements your intuition. Specifically I'm focusing on this quote from your text: *Think of this special type of composition as molding/transposing the X-axis on the graph/curve of the outer function in the composition and then draw the graph of the inner function on previously modified coordinates plane.*

I'll start with a bunch of definitions. I want to create a new curve called $f \hat \circ g$, where $f$ is the "base function" that defines the high-level shape, and $g$ is the "inner function" that impacts the smaller-scale movements. This will need to be a parametric curve because in general the graphs you want are not single-valued functions.

View the graph of $f$ as a parametric curve: $\mathbf r(t) = (t, f(t))$. This has tangent vector $\mathbf r'(t) = (1, f(t))$, and by rotating 90 degrees we can get a normal vector $\mathbf n(t) = (-f(t), 1)$. Define $\mathbf N(t)$ to be the *unit length* normal vector, i.e. $\mathbf N(t) = \frac{\mathbf n(t)}{\|\mathbf n(t)\|}$.

Let $L(t)$ be the arc length of $\mathbf r$ on the interval from $0$ to $t$. Then to follow your intuition, we'll want to build each point on our final curve by combining information from $f(t)$ with an offset from $g(L(t))$. In particular, the final formula will be:
$$f \hat \circ g(t) = \mathbf r(t) + g(L(t)) \mathbf N(t)$$

To test the formula, I implemented the new composition in Mathematica and I plotted the same test cases you used in the question. The graphs came out looking extremely similar to your example graphs, so I think the test is a success. I'm including my code for completeness; even if you don't use Mathematica, I think you could type basically the same thing in any CAS or even Python if you wanted to play with this operation some more.

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := Cos[x]
n[t_] := {-f'[t], 1};
nn[t_] := n[t]/Norm[n[t]]
fog[t_] := r[t] + g[ArcLength[r[s], {s, 0., t}]]*nn[t]
ParametricPlot[fog[t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image: first example]

```
f[x_] := Cos[x]
g[x_] := Cos[6 x]/6
n[t_] := {-f'[t], 1};
nn[t_] := n[t]/Norm[n[t]]
fog[t_] := r[t] + g[ArcLength[r[s], {s, 0., t}]]*nn[t]
ParametricPlot[fog[t], {t, -8, 8}]
```

[image: composition of two cosine waves]

Pretty cool!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The thing with parametric curves it's pretty much what I did in desmos to obtain those images. I was just hoping there's more to this stuff that I can read about. I guess I'll proceed with the research on my own.